# Paperclip Fail with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What are some possible implications for Image upload with Paperclip working on my local machine but not when deployed to Heroku?

When its deployed to Heroku, the image won't save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't write directly to Heroku's file system, so I am assuming that is your problem. It makes sense to use something like Amazon s3 for image storing. Take a look at this: [Amazon S3 in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)

Once you have configured your s3, you want to change the paperclip's `has_attached_file` to something like this:

```
has_attached_file :my_picture, 
    :styles => { :medium => "275x275>" },
    :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "user/:attachment/:style/:id.:extension"
```

Where s3.yml would be the configuration file where you define access keys, buckets...

It should look something like this:

```
production:
 access_key_id: [Your Key]
 secret_access_key: [Your Secret]
 bucket: [Your bucket name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another [guide/article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) written by one of Paperclip's developers, it explains in detail how to integrate Paperclip with Heroku and S3